# Is Sandbox user account is linked with certificate and provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have a doubt. I have created sand box user in our developer account.I created a certificates and provisioning profile and created .ipa file.Now I want to change the sandbox user.Should I create another certificates and provisioning profile?or just singin sandbox user in device is enough?.Is sandbox user account is connected with certificates and  provisioning profile? Please clear my doubt.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'sandbox' user in your developer account?

Comment: in developer account,I created sandbox tester. And I ran my app on device and used that sandbox tester... created .ipa file. Now I add another sandbox tester. Now my doubt was As i created another sandbox user should I create anthoer .ipa file or just to login with new sand box tester is enough????    Now I am cleared need not create new .ipa file.We can use old .ipd file just login with the newly created sandbox tester is enough